# I don't know why this script wont't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

For some reason this script won't work. I'm using express, socket.io, jade and node.js. 
Here is the script:

```
var socket = io.connect();

function addMessage(msg) 
{
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateTime = currentDate.getDate() + "/" +
(currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + 
currentDate.getFullYear() + "@"
currentDate.getHours() + ":" +
currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" +
currentDate.getSeconds();
$("#historyView").append("<p>" + dateTime + " - " + msg + "</p>");
}

function sentMessage()
{
    if ($("#arduinoInput").val() != "")
    {
    socket.emit("message", $("#arduinoInput").val());
    addMessage($('#arduinoInput').val(), new Date().toISOString(), true);
    $("#arduinoInput").val("");
    }
  }

socket.on("message", function(message){
    addMessage(message);
});

$document.ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
    sentMessage();
});
});
```

It doesn't even clear the text box. Here is the jade page:

```
doctype 5
html
head
    title Arduino Controller 2
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js");
    script(src="script.js")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css")
body
    div.container
        header
            h1 Arduino Controller 2
        center
            div#historyView
            input(type="text")#arduinoInput
            button#submit Send
```

I've been trying to debug this for awhile. I'm running this on Mac OS X 10.9 if that helps.

Comment: What does that mean *"won't work"* ? What's the result of your debug session ?

Comment: Looks like OP has skipped the "debug session". In addition what hexacyanide has answered, there's also this line: `currentDate.getFullYear() + "@"` lacking trailing `+`.

Comment: It does not do anything when you press send. It does not even clear the text box so I know that it isn't a socket.io problem

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any other code, this would be incorrect:

```
$document.ready();
```

It is likely you meant to attach a ready handler to the document, which should look like this:

```
$(document).ready();
```

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: @blockaj, that did something and it actually made your code work on `document.ready` event, you've used it in wrong way but there may other errors.

Comment: @ hexa: It's not a *syntax* error. It may be an error, unless the OP has done `var $document = $(document);` somewhere. :-)